# How to add multiple selected item on a text box

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to insert longlistselector selected items into a textbox.
 for that i use

```
var item = MainLongListSelectorcompose.SelectedItem as Smallemotions;
composertxtbx.Text = item.Emoticons;
```

The problem is if i select more than one item from longlistselector, it will replace the textbox content.

Comment: You can than use composertxtbx.Text = composertxtbx.Text + item.Emoticons; Obviously that is based on your business use cases.

Comment: thanks Mr.PratikGoyal